# How to hide the Android softkeyboard while focus a textfield in a webview?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to to create an android app to display a webapplication on a mobile device with an integrated keyboard.
Therefor I open a webview, where on each content change the first textfield automatically gets focused.
The problem is that the softkeyboard always pops up when the first textfield gets focus.
Is there a possibility to keep the focus, but hide the softkeyboard?

I tried to implement an onFocusChangeListener with an InputMethodManager, and to add android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" to my androidManifest.xml, but both approaches didn't change anything.

This is how I set up my webview:

```java
public class OpenWebviewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_webview);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wamasWebView);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String url = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        myWebView.loadUrl(url);

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        OnFocusChangeListener ofcListener = new MyFocusChangeListener();
        myWebView.setOnFocusChangeListener(ofcListener);
   }
}
```

And this is how I used the OnFocusChangeListener:

```java
private class MyFocusChangeListener implements OnFocusChangeListener {

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

And here is the activity part of my androidManifest.xml

```xml
<activity android:name=".OpenWebviewActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden">
</activity>
```

It would be okay if the keyboard pops up when the user touches on a textfield, it should just hide if the textfield is automatically focused.
I'm new to android, so maybe my approach was completely wrong.

Thanks for any advice!

Edit: Added the new androidManifest.xml part

Comment: I have done this in that particular activity from `manifest`.. `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"` works fine for me.. If you have a toolbar or anything else in that webview xml give focus there..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden" does not affect my softkeyboard behavior, and I don't have anything else in the webview.